# How should I deal with an occasionally corrupted file?

Tags: c#, file

I have an app that saves data in sessions of 15 minutes each. The saved data accumulates until it reaches a size threshold and then starts deleting the oldest data first. However, the data includes sensitive information, so when the data is written is scrubbed from the file, including the last modified date. I use a counter as part of the file name to keep track of the file order. I need to keep track of the counter through reboots and even if the data itself is deleted. As a solution, to determine the oldest file, I keep a simple counter in a 1-line text file. Every 15 minutes, I read from this file, increment the counter, and write the result back to the file:

```
int catalogNumber = 0;
if (File.Exists(catalogFilePath))
{
    catalogNumber = int.Parse(File.ReadAllText(catalogFilePath);
    catalogNumber++;
}

File.WriteAllText(catalogFilePath, catalogNumber.ToString());
```

This works almost always. However, once in a great while (maybe once a year or so), something gets messed up. I suspect it's because a user has killed the app during the short window when File.WriteAllText() is being called, but the result is that the next time through the loop the read fails. My question is how can I ensure that I never lose the counter?

Comment: You could also enumerate the files, order them by last modified date and delete all files after the 15th.

Comment: File.Exists() is evil, it never ever means "the file content the way I want it exists".  So don't use it, using try/catch with file system operations is essential.

Comment: *I need to keep track of the counter * I was with you until this sentence. Sort of came out of nowhere. What counter? If you're counting 15-minute intervals, I suggest storing a time stamp instead. You can then compute the counter as needed by calculating the difference between the stored time stamp and the system time and dividing by 15.

Comment: `File.Exists()` should be renamed to `File.MaybeExistsButWhoKnows()`

Comment: Here is an issue ,`WriteAllText` uses a `StreamWriter` internally, with a small buffer size. There is an edge case that only a partial file gets written on abnormal shutdown. A solution to this might to use your own streams and increase the buffer (far from bullet proof). Another would be to write to a temporary file, then when its finished, `File.Move` to the actual filename, this will use the OS file move methods and will be atomicish (disregarding bad sectors, and invoking supernatural beings ect)

Comment: @CodeCaster I can't use last modified date because that's part of the scrubbed data: it's reset to a default value.

Comment: @JohnWu Sorry, you're right. I should have said "I use a counter to keep track of which file is next since the date is scrubbed." Edited for more clarity.

Comment: I suggest you use 16 file names, one of which is always missing. The missing file tells you which one needs to be written next. Before you write it delete the next file. If there is a failure, there will be two missing files; just write the next one as usual. If you do everything in the right order, this scheme will naturally be fault tolerant.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, John -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a likely culprit.

`WriteAllText` uses a `StreamWriter` internally, with a small buffer size.

The buffer is the internal array used by a stream, when the array is full it tends to flush it to disk, that's to say a stream isn't atomically written to disk.

As such, there is an edge case that only a partial file gets written on abnormal shutdown (when the `WriteAllText` only partially finished).

A solution to this might to use your own *streams* and increase the buffer beyond the size of the data, however this is far from bullet proof.

Another solution would be to write to a temporary file, then when it's finished, use `File.Move` to move the temp file to your actual destination file. `File.Move` will use the native *win32 api* `MoveFile` it will in turn be handled internally by the Operating System atomically (all or nothing).

The result will be, you will have a complete destination file or no file / no change, depending on what you are doing (and disregarding any other problem).

Comment: thank you for the comments! How would using my own stream help with abnormal shutdown? 

I like the File.Move idea, but is there a good way to make sure the content is always correct and not 1 off if there's an abnormal shutdown?

Comment: @LucasS the stream is not the solution. Yes if there is an abnormal shutdown, there will be a partial temporary file and no updated file. You will have to keep track of whether a file complete at the end of your method. if there is, you will need to try again on restart.